# Feeding in custom image into tensorflow during inference

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a model lik this

```
def inference(images, reuse=False, trainable=True):
    coarse1_conv = conv2d('coarse1', images, [11, 11, 3, 96], [96], [1, 4, 4, 1], padding='VALID', reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse1 = tf.nn.max_pool(coarse1_conv, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='VALID', name='pool1')
    coarse2_conv = conv2d('coarse2', coarse1, [5, 5, 96, 256], [256], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse2 = tf.nn.max_pool(coarse2_conv, ksize=[1, 3, 3, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME', name='pool1')
    coarse3 = conv2d('coarse3', coarse2, [3, 3, 256, 384], [384], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse4 = conv2d('coarse4', coarse3, [3, 3, 384, 384], [384], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse5 = conv2d('coarse5', coarse4, [3, 3, 384, 256], [256], [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID', reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse6 = fc('coarse6', coarse5, [6*10*256, 4096], [4096], reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse7 = fc('coarse7', coarse6, [4096, 4070], [4070], reuse=reuse, trainable=trainable)
    coarse7_output = tf.reshape(coarse7, [-1, 55, 74, 1])
    return coarse7_output
```

I am calling it using

```
logits = model.inference(images, keep_conv, keep_hidden)
```

Here images is basically read from a queuerunner like this

```
images, depths, invalid_depths = dataset.csv_inputs(TRAIN_FILE)

def csv_inputs(self, csv_file_path):
        filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([csv_file_path], shuffle=True)
        reader = tf.TextLineReader()
        _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)
        filename, depth_filename = tf.decode_csv(serialized_example, [["path"], ["annotation"]])
        # input
        jpg = tf.read_file(filename)
        image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpg, channels=3)
        image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)       
        # target
        depth_png = tf.read_file(depth_filename)
        depth = tf.image.decode_png(depth_png, channels=1)
        depth = tf.cast(depth, tf.float32)
        depth = tf.div(depth, [255.0])
        #depth = tf.cast(depth, tf.int64)
        # resize
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, (IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH))
        depth = tf.image.resize_images(depth, (TARGET_HEIGHT, TARGET_WIDTH))
        invalid_depth = tf.sign(depth)
        # generate batch
        images, depths, invalid_depths = tf.train.batch(
            [image, depth, invalid_depth],
            batch_size=self.batch_size,
            num_threads=4,
            capacity= 50 + 3 * self.batch_size,
        )
        return images, depths, invalid_depths
```

I am now trying to run the model by providing a single image.

```
logits_val = sess.run([ logits, what_do_i_have-to put here], feed_dict={keep_conv: 0.8, keep_hidden: 0.5})
```

I have tried different ways of reading and inserting the image. However, I dont think I am doing it correctly. How do I feed in data into my model?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to put it somewhere else! :) Namely, in the feed_dict argument. The first argument of [`sess.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#run) is *what value you want to get back*, so that's just the logits. So pick out one image from the return values of your `csv_inputs()`, supposing you assign that to `my_image` (make sure to keep the batch dimension even if it's just 1), then the command to infer the network on it would be:

```
logits_val = sess.run([ logits ], feed_dict={ images: my_image, keep_conv: 0.8, keep_hidden: 0.5})
```

Note, that you have to be careful with `images` because it means different things at different parts of you code, however. Once it's a placeholder for data, and at other parts it holds the data itself.

Comment: Let me try tht out